# What is the difference between readall and read+hasdata?

Tags: matlab, matlab-table

I found that the functions of readall and read+hasdata seem to be exactly the same. read+hasdata is a loop body, is it less efficient? So in any case you should avoid using read+hasdata? Why does matlab also provide the hasdata function?
In what scenario is it more meaningful to use read+hasdata?

[hasdata](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.io.datastore.hasdata.html?s_tid=srchtitle_site_search_1_hasdata)

```
ds = datastore('mapredout.mat');
while hasdata(ds)
   T = read(ds);
end
```

[readall](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.io.datastore.readall.html?s_tid=srchtitle_site_search_1_readall)

```
ds = datastore('mapredout.mat');
readall(ds)
```

Answer (score 0):

In this example, there's not really any appreciable difference. However, consider the case where your `datastore` refers to thousands of data files which contain many gigabytes of data. In that case, it is not practicable to call `readall`, so you instead proceed by calling `read` to get chunks of data that you can fit in memory.

[This page](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/import_export/read-and-analyze-data-in-a-tabulartextdatastore.html) shows an example of reading from a large text file in chunks to calculate aggregate quantities without ever having the entire data set in memory at one time.

Comment: Thanks for your help."it is not practicable to call readall, so you instead proceed by calling read to get chunks of data that you can fit in memory."----------yes, use read can fit in memory. But use read+hasdata can not fit in memory?I don't know if my understanding is right

Comment: Thanks for your example：https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/import_export/read-and-analyze-data-in-a-tabulartextdatastore.html     In this case,use  tall array+gather is better?